# How to check if an entity object has been modified before saving it?

Tags: 7, entities

When calling the `save()` method on an entity, the timestamp value for last modified is always updated, regardless of whether the entity was actually modified.

Is there a way to check if an entity object has actually been modified before saving it?

I haven't seen any flags, similar to `is_new`, but perhaps there is a method or PHP function that can be used?

Simple example:

```
$entity_type = 'my_entity';
$entity_id = 1;
$entity = entity_load_single($entity_type, $entity_id);

// With EMW.
$entity_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);
$entity_wrapper->save();

// Witout EMW.
$entity->save();
```

In these cases the modified property of the entity is still updated even though nothing was actually changed.

Comment: are you looking for a timestamp of last edit with changes ?

Comment: Not quite, I'm talking about being able to tell if an instantiated entity object (possibly using entity wrapper) has actually been modified (value that was loaded has been changed). E.g. `$entity->isDirty()` or something.

Comment: if you are using nodes, on node_update the node also contains node->original so you can compare them and set a flag. Not sure if entities has the equivalent.